# pipe output of ls to echo to append prefix to list

Tags: bash

I am trying to pipe data to split in a bash script. I have a directory that consists of

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
...
```

I would like to make a summary file that lists these files in batches of a thousand. The following gets me close

```
ls *.txt | sort | split -l 1000
```

My problem is I want it to look like

```
file a.txt
file b.txt 
etc...
```

my plan was to add an echo file ???? in there to make that happen but I cannot pipe ls to echo

Any ideas

Comment: Maybe use `sed`? `ls *.txt | sed 's/^/file /' | sort | split -l 1000`

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse the result of `ls`, you might better do something like this:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -exec echo "file" {} \; | sort
```